# ¿Cómo saber si un módulo esta instalado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Hola como puedo saber que módulos o paquetes están instalados en Python 3, para saber si hay que instalar el modulo faltante.

Comment: relacionado : [¿Cómo verificar la versión de los modulos instalados?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188044/c%C3%B3mo-verificar-la-versi%C3%B3n-de-los-modulos-instalados)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Si quieres saber si un módulo está correctamente instalado basta con intentar importarlo en un script o en el intérprete interactivo:

```
import nombre_del_módulo
```

Si no está disponible lanzará una excepción:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
>     import requests
> ImportError: No module named requests
> ```

La cuál eventualmente puedes manejar:

```
try:
    import nombre_del_módulo
except ImportError:
    # Que hacer si el módulo no se puede importar
    print("Módulo no instalado"
```

Desde la terminal puedes ver si el módulo está instalado con PIP:

> $ python -m pip show numpy

Lo cual muestra información detallada del paquete si está instalado o nada si el paquete no se encuentra.

Si quieres listar los módulos instalados tienes múltiples opciones:

- En el intérprete interactivo hay varias formas usando `help()`:

  - `help('modules')`
  - `help('modules package')`
- Si quieres conocer los módulos instalados via `pip` puedes:

  - `pip freeze` desde la consola(cmd)
  - `pip list` desde la consola(cmd)
  - Crear un script usando `pip.get_installed_distributions()`:

    ```
    import pip

    lista_paquetes = sorted([(p.key, p.version)
                            for p in pip.get_installed_distributions()])

    print("{0:<30}{1:<30}".format('Nombre de Paquete', 'Versión'))
    for paquete, version in lista_paquetes:
        print("{0:<30}{1:<30}".format(paquete, version))
    ```

    Salida:

    > ```
    > Nombre de Paquete             Versión                       
    > aiohttp                       2.0.2                         
    > appdirs                       1.4.2                         
    > async-timeout                 1.2.0                         
    > chardet                       2.3.0                         
    > docutils                      0.13.1                        
    > kivy                          1.9.1
    > ..........
    > ```

    ---

    > **Nota**: a partir de PIP 10 importar funciones desde PIP no es permitido y dicha función ha sido trasladada siendo estrictos nunca fueron consideradas realmente como públicas por los desarrolladores de PIP). Si necesitamos usar PIP para listar módulo o eventualmente instalar paquetes desde un script Python, podemos recurrir a `subprocess`.
  - Usar `subprocess` para ejecutar pip como subproceso, por ejemplo:

    ```
    import subprocess

    sub = subprocess.run(["pip", "list", '--disable-pip-version-check'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines=True
                        )
    pkgs = (line.rstrip().split() for line in sub.stdout.split("\n")[2: -1])

    for paquete, version in pkgs:
        print(paquete, version)
    ```
- Algo más general para listar **todos los módulos disponibles** puedes usar `pkgutil.iter_modules()`:

  ```
  from pkgutil import iter_modules
  print(*(m[1] for m in  iter_modules()), sep='\n')
  ```

Hay mil formas más de hacer esto.

Comment: y que sucede cuando aunque tengas el modulo pip instalado, el sistema (python) no te deja instalar el modulo que estas buscando? En especial considerando que tiene varios FORTRAN compilers en tu PC???

Comment: Hola @ArkVzla bienvenid@ a [es.so], tu problema no está aparentemente relacionado con la pregunta  (listar módulos instados). Al menos por lo que entiendo de tu comentario, tu problema es al instalar un módulo vía pip. Si tienes problemas en la instalación te sugiero que [crees una nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y agregues toda la información relevante (módulo, versión de Python y pip, cómo lo intentas instalar, sistema operativo, error que te genera completo, lo que comentas sobre los compiladores Fortran, etc). Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

En teoría desde el consola de comandos puede obtener los módulos instalados con la siguiente instrucción [help()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help)

```
help('modules')
```

Si desea preguntar por un módulo especifico, se le envía por parámetro dicho nombre

```
help('django') // return info  , instalado
help ('numpy') // return false , no instalado
```

Answer (score 1):

De hecho, ni siquiera tienes que entrar al IDLE de Python. En un una sola línea y desde tu terminal puedes verificarlo:

```
$ python3 -c "import flask"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
$
```

Aquellos módulos que existan simplemente no arrojarán error:

```
$ python3 -c "import pprint"
$
```

El flag `-c` le indica a Python que vas a ejecutar insrtucciones desde una cadena de texto. En este caso solo estamos importando para verificar que esté instalado.

Otra forma (si trabajas desde Linux), como veo que estás usando `pip`, es usar el comando `freeze` mezclado con un `grep`:

```
$ pip3 freeze | grep virtual
virtualenv==15.1.0
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.2
```

Como ves, ninguna de estas formas requiere que entres al IDLE de Python para lograr lo que deseas. Puedes hacerlo en una sola línea.