# ¿Cómo verificar la versión de los modulos instalados?

Tags: python

Tengo instalado la versión de Python 3.6.2 de 64 bits sobre Windows 7, quisiera verificar la versión de algunos módulos o paquetes que utilizo a menudo, como `numpy`, `pandas`, `matplotlib`...

¿Cual sería una forma sencilla, ya que soy nuevo en Python?

Comment: Si los instalaste con `pip`, puedes poner `pip freeze` y eso te dará la lista de todos los paquetes instalados y la versión de cada uno. Si fue con `conda` tienes `conda list`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No existe una forma que asegure siempre obtener la versión de un paquete/módulo, esto puede depender del método de instalación/administrador de paquetes usado y de características propias de cada librería (que puede incluso no exponer esta información en algunos casos). Genéricamente hay dos formas de obtener esta información:

### Desde la terminal, si se usa PIP para instalar los paquetes

En este caso podemos obtener las versiones de los mismos de diferentes formas:

- [**`pip list`**](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/). Muestra los paquetes instalados junto a su versión, tabulados y ordenados alfabéticamente:

  ```
  $ python3 -m pip list

  Package         Version  
  --------------- ---------   
  matplotlib      2.2.2    
  mypy            0.620    
  nltk            3.3      
  Nuitka          0.5.32.3 
  numpy           1.15.0   
  opencv-python   3.4.2.17 
  pandas          0.23.4
  ```
- [**`pip freeze`**](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/). En este caso muestra los paquetes y su versión pero en el formato propio para requirements.txt, menos ameno al usuario:

  ```
  $ python3 -m pip freeze

  beautifulsoup4==4.6.1
  matplotlib==2.2.2
  mypy==0.620
  nltk==3.3
  Nuitka==0.5.32.3
  numpy==1.15.0
  opencv-python==3.4.2.17
  pandas==0.23.4
  ```
- [**`pip show`**](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/). Permite mostrar información detallada de uno o varios paquetes (nombre, descripción, versión, autor, email, homepage, directorio de instalación, paquetes requeridos, paquetes que lo requieren) instalados:

  ```
  $ python3 -m pip show numpy pandas matplotlib 

  Name: numpy
  Version: 1.15.0
  Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
  Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
  Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
  Author-email: None
  License: BSD
  Location: .pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  Requires: 
  Required-by: scipy, pandas, opencv-python, matplotlib
  ---
  Name: pandas
  Version: 0.23.4
  Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
  Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
  Author: None
  Author-email: None
  License: BSD
  Location: .pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  Requires: pytz, numpy, python-dateutil
  Required-by: 
  ---
  Name: matplotlib
  Version: 2.2.2
  Summary: Python plotting package
  Home-page: http://matplotlib.org
  Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
  Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
  License: BSD
  Location: .pyenv/versions/3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  Requires: kiwisolver, six, python-dateutil, pyparsing, numpy, pytz, cycler
  Required-by:
  ```

### Desde el propio script/intérprete interactivo

En este caso tenemos también varias posibilidades:

- Usar el atributo especial `__version__`:

  ```
  >>> import pandas
  >>> import matplotlib
  >>> import numpy

  >>> pandas.__version__
  '0.23.4'
  >>> matplotlib.__version__
  '2.2.2'
  >>> numpy.__version__
  '1.15.0'
  ```

  > Si bien es la forma estándar de definir la versión de un módulo a partir de [PEP 396](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/), hay librerias que no lo implementan o lo hacen solo a nivel de subpaquetes/módulos, cómo es el caso de `lxml`.
- De tener instalado `setuptools` (bastante probable) podemos usar  `pkg_resources`:

  ```
  >>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("numpy").version
  '1.15.0'
  >>> pkg_resources.get_distribution("lxml").version
  '4.2.4'
  ```

El uso de `pip list/freeze/show` y de `__version__` posiblemente sean las formas más universales, pero no siempre están disponibles en todos los casos. Hay paquetes que definen sus propias formas de acceder a la versión instalada, por ejemplo:

[¿Como sé qué versión de Django estoy usando?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172513/15089)

> **NOTA:** dado que usas Python 3 en Windows, de no estar usando entornos virtuales, la forma más simple de ejecutar intérprete determinado en
>   CMD, sobretodo si se tienen varias versiones de Python instaladas, es
>   usar [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), que ya tienes instalado:
>
> ```
> py -3.6 -m pip list
> py -2.7 -m pip list
> py -3.6 mi_modulo.py
> ...
> ```